# Highlight differences in same column for a group in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have created a pivot table with Column A and Column B. 
Column A has one to many relation with Column B.

I want to highlight Column A, if there is a difference in Column B values in its scope. For example,

```
A            B
ABC          10
             10
XYZ          20
             25
```

In this case, XYZ has 2 different values in column B. I want to highlight this. How can this be done in excel?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ValueB As String
Dim lRowA As Long

    Set WS = Application.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = 1

    'Get the last row that has data in columnB
    lastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through all the rows
    Do While lRow <= lastRow

        'If we have data in columnA, record it
        If WS.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            ValueB = WS.Range("B" & lRow).Value
            'Keep track of the row that we found new columnA data on
            lRowA = lRow
        Else
            'We don't have data in columnA, Compare what we found in 
            'columnB of the last row where we had data in columnA with this row
            If ValueB <> WS.Range("B" & lRow).Value Then
                WS.Range("A" & lRowA).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                WS.Range("A" & lRowA).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                WS.Range("A" & lRowA).Interior.Color = 255
            End If
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        WS.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

End Sub
```